# $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|p(v-r,x)-p(u-r,x)|\,dx \leq C\frac{v-u}{u-r}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Consider $p(u,x)=(4\pi u)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4u}},u>0,x\in \mathbb{R}^d.$

Prove that there exists $C>0$ such that for all $0<u\leq v,r\in[0,u[,$ $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|p(v-r,x)-p(u-r,x)|\, dx \leq C\frac{v-u}{u-r}$$

Any ideas how to prove it?

Comment: Here they cover some Holder/L1 estimates for the semigroup that you could try: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/parabolic.pdf eg. Remark 1.4

Comment: I do not think we need them here, there might be easier ways.

Comment: Actually I did a proof without Young inequality.

Comment: Something is wrong here: under your conditions, $u-u\le0$.

Comment: Problem corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Letting $s:=u-r$ and $t:=v-r$, rewrite the inequality in question as
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\R^d}dx\,|p(t,x)-p(s,x)| \le C\Big(\frac ts-1\Big) \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
given that $0<s\le t<\infty$.

Note that
\begin{equation*}
    |p(t,x)-p(s,x)|\le\int_s^t dw\,|D_w p(w,x)|,
\end{equation*}
where $D_w$ is the operator of partial differentiation with respect to $w$. So,
\begin{equation*}
        \int_{\R^d}dx\,|p(t,x)-p(s,x)| \le\int_s^t dw\, \int_{\R^d}dx\,|D_w p(w,x)|. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\R^d}dx\,D_w p(w,x)=D_w\int_{\R^d}dx\, p(w,x)=D_w1=0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    D_w p(w,x)=p(w,x)\Big(\frac{|x|^2}{4w^2}-\frac d{2w}\Big). 
\end{equation*}
So, with $z_+:=\max(0,z)$ for real $z$,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\R^d}dx\,|D_w p(w,x)|
    =2\int_{\R^d}dx\,p(w,x)\Big(\frac d{2w}-\frac{|x|^2}{4w^2}\Big)_+
    \le2\int_{\R^d}dx\,p(w,x)\frac d{2w}=\frac dw. 
\end{equation*}

Thus, by \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
        \int_{\R^d}dx\,|p(t,x)-p(s,x)| \le d\,\ln\frac ts,
\end{equation*}
whence \eqref{0} follows, with $C=d$.